# Why does open make my file descriptor 0?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I'm working on a program that is using a pipe and forks and need to change the write end to an output file.  But when I open a file the file descriptor is 0 which is usually stdin but which I think is the cause of some of my problems.  Here is my code

```
if (outputfd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC) == -1) 
{
    // open failed
}
```

Can someone let me know why it is 0? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're comparing it to `-1`.

`outputfd` doesn't get the result of `open`. It gets the result of the check for `-1`.

Answer (score 7):

`outputfd` in your line of code is not the output file descriptor but rather is equal to `FALSE` (0). This is because the file descriptor returned by `open` is not `== -1`

It should read:

```
outputfd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
if (outputfd < 0)
{
   // error handling code
}
```

Or it should read:

```
if ( ( outputfd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC) ) == -1)
{
    // error handling code
}
```

Note that this required 3 extra parentheses - one right parenthesis and two left.

Answer (score 5):

Just illustrating [doron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795351/why-does-open-make-my-file-descriptor-0/3795395#3795395):

```
>> outputfd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC) == -1)
```

Let's simplify: first remove errors and add extra punctutation to make it look like an actual stement

```
   outputfd = open("file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC) == -1;
```

Now, replace function parameters with a placeholder

```
   outputfd = open(<PLACEHOLDER>) == -1;
```

Add parenthesis

```
   outputfd = (open(<PLACEHOLDER>) == -1);
```

When is the result of open() -1? When the operation failed. So let's assume the operation **didn't** fail and replace the open with a positive number

```
   outputfd = (<POSITIVENUMBER> == -1);
```

No positive number can ever be equal to -1 (barring conversion problems) so the equality test is always false ... and false, in `C` is, by definition, 0

```
   outputfd = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, relational operators have [higher precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than assignment operators.